# need clarification for Constructors in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I want to know whether my understanding on the constructors is correct or not. I just tried to attempt a quiz for constructors but confused whether my understanding is correct or not

--> Every class needs at least one constructor defined - False (In C#, if you don't provide one, the compiler automatically provides a default constructor.)

--> It’s possible to avoid a class being instantiated by simply having only a private constructor on it. – False (A private constructor is a special instance constructor. It is generally used in classes that contain static members only. If a class has one or more private constructors and no public constructors, other classes (except nested classes) cannot create instances of this class.)

--> A static constructor in a non­static class is called once on each object creation. – False (If a static constructor has been called once, compiler will not call it again, it will get called once only .The execution of a static constructor is triggered by the first of the following events to occur within an application domain: 1. An instance of the class type is created. 2. Any of the static members of the class type are referenced.)

-->You can specify on the constructor which classes of interfaces that class is inheriting
( i don't know please clarify )

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> --> Every class needs at least one constructor defined - False (In C#, if you don't provide one, > > the compiler automatically provides a default constructor.)
>   **- Your understanding is Correct**
>
> --> It’s possible to avoid a class being instantiated by simply having only a private constructor on it. – False (A private constructor is a
>   special instance constructor. It is generally used in classes that
>   contain static members only. If a class has one or more private
>   constructors and no public constructors, other classes (except nested
>   classes) cannot create instances of this class.)
>   **- You can have a private constructor, in which case other classes cannot create instance of it (but why will you do that?)- People do that to put some control in object's instantiation, as what they do commonly in some design patterns. In a nutshell, you can still create an instance of a class with private constructor thru some other means (e.g. from static methods).**
>
> --> A static constructor in a non­static class is called once on each object creation. – False (If a static constructor has been called
>   once, compiler will not call it again, it will get called once only
>   .The execution of a static constructor is triggered by the first of
>   the following events to occur within an application domain: 1. An
>   instance of the class type is created. 2. Any of the static members of
>   the class type are referenced.) 
>   **- Your understanding is Correct**
>
> -->You can specify on the constructor which classes of interfaces that class is inheriting ( i don't know please clarify )
>   **- False, You specify in the class declaration itself the interfaces or classes that the class is going to inherit not in the constructor**

Comment: >but why will you do that?  For example [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)